# Homescreen/launcher with Monodroid crash

Tags: android, xamarin.android, startup, homescreen

I'm trying to create a launcher/homescreen. The application crashes on restart.

Debugger displays : "Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider". You have to wait a long time before the MonoRuntimeProvider is started, and then the app works. Any ideas to resolve this problem?

Activity1.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "Test application", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        try
        {


        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);


        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("TestError","Test Error:" + ex.Message);
        }
        // 

    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="internalOnly" package="Test.AndroidMono" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="test">
  <application android:label="Test AndroidMono" >
       <activity android:name="monoandroidapplication2.Activity1"

               android:launchMode="singleInstance"
               android:stateNotNeeded="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: The only things I don't recognize are launchMode and stateNotNeeded. You can try without those and see if it helps.  If not, adding the full exception might help.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution:

MonoRuntimeProvider is required for debugging. Once I made a release, it worked perfectly...